# How can I see the output from .Q.hg/.Q.hp?

Tags: kdb

I am using `.Q.hp` to send a message to symphony bot .

```
.Q.hp[hsym`$"host";"";"chatRoomName;someHTMLTable"]
```

If I run the above in the browser I usually get something back like "duplicate message" or "room does not exist", but `.Q.hp` only returns an empty string `""`

How can I see if a message is being received from the alert bot?
Is `.Q.hp` asynchronous and is kdb not waiting for anything back?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom .Q.hp2 that returns a response which is a two-item list (of strings) - by default .Q.hp only returns the second item in that list. The first item in the response might give you the info you're looking for.

```
q).Q.hp2:{.Q.hmb[x;`POST;(y;z)]}
q)res:.Q.hp2["http://google.com";.h.ty`json]"my question"
q)res 0
"HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed\r\nallow: GET, HEAD\r\ndate: Wed, 15 Dec 2021 02:09:14 GMT\r\nco..
q)res 1
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial..
```

Tested with v4.0 build 2021.07.12